# Is this Plagiarism? Should I do something?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I was looking to solve a problem and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510343/escape-command-line-arguments-in-c-sharp) SO answer addresses it in a very detailed and peculiar way. By chance I found (what to me seems) the very same answer set in [this](https://newbedev.com/escape-command-line-arguments-in-c) site.

There is no mention where this answer is from. The site reports many other Q&A that are (again to me) a copy cat of SO.

Am I wrong? Do I need to do something?

Comment: Thank you, I though it was plagiarism... but indeed is __scraping__. Yes. I close it.

Comment: It was scraping in this case, but a lot of answers on Stack Overflow are plagiarised from elsewhere, e.g. blog posts. A dead giveaway is if the quality of English is very different from what can be expected from a particular user (e.g., revealed by the user's non-plagiarised answers. Or if the title/first line/first paragraph is in broken English and the rest is in near-perfect English).